# Search for specific Term in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to search for [ERROR] from message field  using term field on Kibana UI.

But it returns all terms like "No Error" , "[ERROR]" but I am trying to get those entries which contains the term "[ERROR]" .

Any idea where I am doing the search wrong or if I can modify it ?

Regards,
Abhay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search functionality in Elasticsearch depends on index configuration during indexing data. If you did not configured any specific mapping, then the [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is applied to the data.

You can check in the console how the Standard Analyzer splits your data into tokens. Try this:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["[ERROR] message", "error message"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

As you will see, both "[ERROR]" and "error" are converted to the same token. To strictly find the term "[ERROR]" you need to configure your index to use [Whitespace Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) and reindex your data.